# Why is my database failing to connect from my front end app, but it works fine from the server with the same credentials?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, next.js

I'm using an Express server connected to a local MySQL database with a Next.js frontend application. I have successfully connected the db to my server and do not have any error messages in my server regarding the db. All my db information is correct in my .env. I am using the npm mysql2 package with my project because mysql was creating weird dependency issues.

I am getting this error when I try to pass information from my front end to my database (for example, through a user registration):

```
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlState: '28000',
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
  sql: undefined
```

Why would I only be having db connection issues when I'm passing info through my registration page on my Next.js app? I also don't understand why the error says I am not using a password when I do have one set. This is my registerRoute in Express:

```
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const router = express.Router();

// Import the database connection
const db = require('../database');

// Registration route
router.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { f_name, l_name, email, password } = req.body;

    // Hash the password
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    // Insert user data into the database using async/await
    const query = `INSERT INTO user (f_name, l_name, email, password, created_at) 
                   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())`;

    // Using db.query as a promise (with .execute())
    const [rows] = await db.execute(query, [f_name, l_name, email, hashedPassword]);

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Registration successful' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error registering user:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred while registering the user' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here's my database.js file:

```
const mysql2 = require ('mysql2');

require('dotenv').config();

const connection = mysql2.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to database.');
});

module.exports = connection.promise();
```

Please help, I'm so confused!

Comment: Can you show us some of your backend code that connects to the database? It doesn't seem to pass either a password or a username properly.

Comment: @LW001 I updated the post with an example. I can show you my database.js file too if that's helpful

Comment: The error message indicates that you're leaving the username and password blank when you connect to the DB. Is that in `database.js`?

Comment: @Barmar I've included my database.js file contents in the post. I have the user name and password there and have tested it without using process.env too, but I still get the same message.

Comment: The problem is probably that the environment is not set up correctly. What does `console.log(process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASS)` show?

Comment: @Barmar it shows my user and pass from my .env file.